# A simple word order question: when turn "please come in" to negative

Tags: word-order

My kid has an English exercise at school, which asked them to turn the sentence **Please come in.** into a negative sentence. I thought that should be very simple, but then I realized that I was not 100% sure about word order here. So, can someone tell which one(s) are correct orders:

> 1. Don't please come in.
> 2. Please don't come in.
> 3. Don't come in please.

It's a very simple question. I personally think they are all ok, but I am not quite sure. Appreciate if someone can help to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you should begin a polite request with a word like *please*. This identifies the statement as a polite request before the actual request.

> **Please** don't come in.

It may be OK to put please at the end, but this will depend on context and emphasis.

> Don't please come in.

doesn't make any sense. You would be negating "please come in", and you wouldn't ask someone to come in after prefacing it with "don't".